# How to parse <Output=T> in Rust macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write a macro that would help me overload operators for custom structs with generic type, inspired by [impl_ops](https://github.com/brianwp3000/impl_ops).

I have no problem parsing `<T : Add>` where the trait `Add` is optional with something like

```
macro_rules! exemple {
    ($op:tt <$($T:ident $(: $C:ident)?),*>) => {}
}

fn main() {
    exemple!(+ <T : Add>);
}
```

but how would I parse `<T : Add<Output=T>>`, the associated output type being also optional for example ?

Comment: Is this the exact input (that is, one identifier, `=` then another identifier)?

Comment: What's wrong with `$(<$t:ident = $v:ident>)?`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I believe the problem is that `>>` will pe passed into the macro as a single token. You suggestion works for `<T : Add<Output=T> >`, but not for `<T : Add<Output=T>>`

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes I thought about that. You can solve that with a hilariously complex tt muncher, but I wouldn't bother and just put the space in there.

Comment: I believe there is no clean way to solve it, because that is the defect of the declarative macros v1.

Comment: @Sprite Define "clean" :P

Comment: Thanks Chayim and Sven, your suggestions work when you put a space between the two tokens > > .